# Importing gradle project, android error

Tags: android, eclipse, git, gradle, libgdx

I am trying to import a libgdx project (desktop, ios and android) to eclipse on my mac, which I have in my local git repository.

When I try to import my project to eclipse ( Import >> Gradle >> Gradle Project, and then add my Root Folder for the whole libgdx project), I try to "Build Model", but then I get an error saying:

```
"SDK location not Found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with and ANDROID_HOME environment variable"
```

I have already set my ANDROID_HOME with

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Development/Tools/android-sdk-mac
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bin
```

but I still get the same error and it doesn't work.

The project was originally created on my windows computer (where everything is working fine) and used git to also have it on my mac for ios stuff.

I have also tried importing it as a local git repo ( Import >> Git >> Projects from Git >> Existing local repository, added the path to the project). When I then choose the wizard for project import as "Import existing projects" it finds none. And when I import as "Use the New Project wizard" and "Import as general project" it doesn't work and I can't run my projects (desktop, ios and android) and sometimes I don't even get my project files up in eclipse.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

PS: Directory:

```
-SpeedRun
--SpeedRun-android
--SpeedRun-desktop
--SpeedRun-ios
```

--SpeedRun-core

Comment: Android Studio (and IntelliJ) has problems with recognition of environment variables when defined on mac. You need to do some search and set then environment variables appropriately. E.g.: http://tomaszwrobel.com/blog/2011/visibility-of-environment-variables-in-gui-applications-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: okay, will do. But importing my as a gradle project is the right way to go right?

Comment: I suppose yes. I don't use eclipse for everyday work unfortunately but the error You get seems to not be linked with failed gradle import.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add file `local.properties` to your project root folder. There you should write location of your Android SDK like this:

```
sdk.dir=/Users/ab/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130917/sdk
```

Comment: thank you! Is it possible to add more than one skd.dir to the local.properties? And where in my directory should I put it? see update OP...

Comment: You should put it in "-SpeedRun" directory. I don't think that you can put more than one sdk.dir . I have 2 different local.properties files on different PC's.

Comment: okay. so I just add it to my .gitignore and create different files. thank you again!