# LibGDX development on many platforms

Tags: java, libgdx, cross-platform, android-2.2-froyo

As a student in a software development class I have been assigned to be part of a group project. Naturally our 4 man group decided to make a game. I suggested LibGDX and got a team member to try it, however, when he tried to import the LibGDX project I created in Windows into eclipse on his linux computer it gave him the could not find sdk message. The build was trying to use the SDK path that I had specified in my own windows computer.

Is it possible to have multiple members on different platforms develop with LibGDX. Please let me know if this is not possible, I have already invested multiple days learning how to develop with LibGDX, and hope that there is some way to develop with windows and linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our team work with libgx projects on MAC, Linux and Windows without any problems. Of course you must properly install Android SDK and JDK in every environment, all other dependencies gradle will download for you. I recommend you to use [git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)) for effective team work. You can create remote repositories for free on [github](https://github.com/) or [bitcucket](http://bitbucket.org).

About IDE, I personally prefer to work with Eclipse, but I know lots of people who works with libgdx in IntelliJ. You should just choose what is more comfortable for you.

P.S In order to fix error with SDK your friend got in Linux look at this answer: [Importing gradle project, android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983221/importing-gradle-project-android-error/23983607#23983607)

Comment: I found out that the local properties had the location of my sdk directory, however, it is not the same location in linux and windows. We are using svn for our version control. I would prefer using git, but our professor wants us to use his svn repo so he can grade and oversee the groups projects easier...  :/

Answer (score 0):

I would actually recommend using a different IDE, I use JGrasp, I recommend that. If it still doesn't work, try to uninstall and reinstall Eclipse, that helps a lot for my friends who use Eclipse, for some reason, Eclipse seems to fix connection issues to dev kits and what not (my friends had the same issue when they were trying to use JSON data). For me, JGrasp handles connection and linking better than Eclipse when it comes to simplicity of it.

Comment: why not use android studio

Comment: I don't think the choice of IDE should really matter, as long as it has the capabilities to do what he needs, it's just a matter of testing it out on several other IDE's to ensure that the problem is not the IDE itself. I personally don't know anything about Android Studio, have you tried using SDK's like this on that specific IDE?

Comment: currently i've tried only eclipse and android studio, and android studio is like 10 times better..

Comment: I'm not sure the LibGDX jar executable can build projects for android studio. I have never used android studio so I wouldn't know

Comment: John, have you tried other IDE's? A quick download on the JGrasp website would easily give you access to a lightweight IDE that can handle nearly all the SDK's that Eclipse can. If it doesn't work then, I would assume that the problem rests with your code, the SDK, the file itself, something OTHER than the IDE. {EDIT} Here, I'll even give you the link for [JGRASP](http://spider.eng.auburn.edu/user-cgi/grasp/grasp.pl?;dl=download_jgrasp.html). If this doesn't, maybe you should put up your code, we might be able to check that too to see if everything checks out (though I doubt it...)